# $\eta$-rules of inductive types in homotopy type theory

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

I'm currently reading Appendix 2 in HoTT-Book, which is a formal presentation of homotopy type theory, and I found that we don't have $\eta$-conversions of inductive types (e.g. the coproduct types).

The question is, is there any reason that we don't have $\eta$-rules?
I know that the type theory becomes extensional (which is not good for homotopy type theory) if we add $\eta$-rule of the identity type. But how about other inductive types?

For example, for closed types $A,B,C$ and a function $f:A+B\to C$,
can't we prove
$$z:A+B\vdash \mathrm{ind}_{A+B}(x.f(\mathrm{inl}(x)), y.f(\mathrm{inr}(y)), z)\equiv f(z):C$$
judgementally?

Comment: My feeling is that it is consistent to add such a rule, for coproducts. This is because coproducts in the simplicial set model are strict.

Comment: Yes, rules like that for coproducts are consistent.  But there are important models that don't satisfy them, which is one reason to avoid them.  Another reason to avoid them is that they're hard to implement computationally.